# Why am I getting InstrumentedAttribute instead of basequery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created two models in flask using flask_sqlalchemy as follows:

```
class Analytics(db.Model, IdMixin, ModelMixin):
    __tablename__ = "analytics"
    record_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("record.id"), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
    updated_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)

class HitLog(db.Model, IdMixin, TimestampMixin, ModelMixin):
    __tablename__ = "hit_logs"
    record_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("record.id"), nullable=True)
    url = Column(Text, nullable=False, default='')
    ip = Column(String(100), nullable=False, default='0.0.0.0', index=True)
    referer = Column(Text, nullable=False, default='')
    source = Column(String(255), nullable=False, default='', index=True)
    query = Column(Text, nullable=False, default='')
    user_agent = Column(String(255), nullable=False, default='')
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True, index=True)
    updated_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True, index=True)
    deleted_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True, index=True)
```

Both the models are created the same way but still when I check for type, I get different results:

```
print type(Analytics.query)
print type(HitLog.query)
```

Gives me:

```
<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

You have a column named `query` in `HitLog`.

Comment: Ohh.. my bad, it was named as search_query... somehow initial part got deleted...Anyways thanks